# using update statement in sqlite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to update a row in sqlite. My query looks like this

`update name="aaa",publisher="ppp",price="111" where bookid=5 and booktype="comic"`

I want to update by using  the following update command .

`int android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)`

What should be the parameters for "whereClause" and "whereArgs". I am searching in Internet but I am not getting related examples. please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can update it using this code:

**DatabaseCreator.class:**

```
public class DatabaseCreator extends  SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DB_NAME="database_name";
    private static final int DB_VER=1;      

    private static final String TABLE_NAME="<table creation query>";

    public DatabaseCreator(Context context) {
        super(context,DB_NAME, null, DB_VER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

        database.execSQL(TABLE_NAME); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int arg1, int arg2) {

        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name");            

        onCreate(database);
    }
}
```

Now use below code where you need to update the row:

```
DatabaseCreator dbcreator=new DatabaseCreator(context);
SQLiteDatabase sqdb=dbcreator.getWritableDatabase();

ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
values.put("name","aaa");
values.put("publisher","ppp");
values.put("price","111");

int id=sqdb.update("table_name",values,"bookid='5' and booktype='comic'",null);
```

Comment: Hi , instead of passing null I want to pass an String array that contains '5' and 'comic'. How to do this

Comment: you don't need to pass them explicitly 2nd time. see the query properly.i have already put that condition in 3rd argument.

Comment: can I use like this                                                 int id=sqdb.update("table_name",values,"bookid=? and booktype=?",array);  where array contains 5 and comic

Comment: Why is your update() call returning an id #?   The docs say it returns the number of records updated. (Mine always returns 0, even when successful.)

Comment: @Carol: yes...my mistake it was.it would return number of rows updated.But i have no clue why you are getting 0 even when update is successful.

Answer (score 4):

Try this. It could helpful for you

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE DB_TABLE SET YOUR_COLUMN='newValue' WHERE id=6 ");
```

or

```
ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
newValues.put("YOUR_COLUMN", "newValue");
```

or

```
ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
newValues.put("YOUR_COLUMN", "newValue");

String[] args = new String[]{"user1", "user2"};
db.update("YOUR_TABLE", newValues, "name=? OR name=?", args);
```

Answer (score 2):

use this code

```
public void updatefriendpic(String fuid, String temp, String temp1) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(THUMB_FRIEND, temp);
        values.put(CONTENT_FRIEND, temp1);
        // update Row
        db.update(TABLE_FRIEND_LIST,values,"_id = '"+fuid+"'",null);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
        Log.d(TAG, "New user update into sqlite: ");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean updateStopnameOfRute(String route,String stopname,int sequence)
        {
            DATABASE_TABLE = "tbl_Stop";
            ContentValues contentvalue=new ContentValues();
            contentvalue.put("stop_name", stopname);
            return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, contentvalue, "route_name='"+route+"'" +"and"+ "stop_sequence="+sequence, null)>0;
        }
```